# List view with scroll pushes out of the UI the footer Xamarin android

Tags: android, css, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have the following android xamarin layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<GridLayout
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/NormalGrid">
    <Button
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:text="Modify normal setting"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/CreateNormalSettingButton" />
    <Button
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:text="Add custom setting"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/CreateCustomSettingButton" />
</GridLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TextView
    android:text="Saved volume/location settings:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/SavedSettingsLabel" />
    <ListView
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:divider="#D3D3D3"
    android:dividerHeight="1dip"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollingCache="true"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:id="@+id/savedSetting" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/resultLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</LinearLayout> </LinearLayout>
```

So at the end of the UI their is a list view and a linear layout that behaves as a footer.

When the list view gets populated with many items, it gets the scroll but the list is growing to the bottom of the UI and is pushing out of the UI the footer.
   The application should keep the scroll in the list view but should keep visible also the footer. So when the list view grows should get its scroll and grow until it meets the footer and that's it, it should not push out of the UI the footer.

By using a relative layout I was able to keep the footer visible but the list view was growing behind it so they were overlaying themselves, so this was also not good. Also I am trying not to set a hard coded height for my list view like: "list view height 100px" since this may look occurred on some devices.

Any ideas how the app should get this kind of smart layout so that it keeps the footer visible and is adding also the scroll to the list view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do like this:

1.Change the property of footer's layout from `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`
to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

just as follows:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
   </LinearLayout>
```

2.add property `android:layout_weight="1"`  for the parent layout of `ListView`

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TextView
    android:text="Saved volume/location settings:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/SavedSettingsLabel" />
    <ListView
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:divider="#D3D3D3"
    android:dividerHeight="1dip"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollingCache="true"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:id="@+id/listview" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So the whole layout is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<GridLayout
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/NormalGrid">
    <Button
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:text="Modify normal setting"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/CreateNormalSettingButton" />
    <Button
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:text="Add custom setting"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/CreateCustomSettingButton" />
</GridLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TextView
    android:text="Saved volume/location settings:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/SavedSettingsLabel" />
    <ListView
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:divider="#D3D3D3"
    android:dividerHeight="1dip"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollingCache="true"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:id="@+id/listview" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <TextView
        android:text="test......"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/resultLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

The result is:

[image]

Note:

Since the width of UI is not fill the screen, so I suggest that you can adjust the property.
change code:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```